# Angular ng-bootstrap datepicker overflow in dialog to main window

Tags: ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, mat-dialog

I am using ng-bootstrap & datepicker in a dialog box (MatDialog).  When opening a datepicker placed at the bottom of the dialog, it results in the dialog scrolling, rather than the datepicker overflowing into the main window.

[image]